Does make custom scorer in sklearn affect loss function of the estimator in gridsearchCV?
I'm using SVM and trying to tune hyperparameters using GridSearchCV. I also made a custom scorer to suit my intended performance metric  and passed it to the scoring parameter.
I'm a little bit confused about whether the loss function will be changed to my custom scorer or the loss function is still hinge loss? Thanks for any help!

The loss function is different from the score.
The scorer is a measure of the accuracy of the predictions, by default, but the loss function is the error between the prediction and the actual values.
